# should claim, which is known and unquestioned fact, be considered notable?

Tags: discussion, questions, notability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If a claim is commonly accepted, does questioning it require a notable counter-claim?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1406/if-a-claim-is-commonly-accepted-does-questioning-it-require-a-notable-counter-c)

I've voted to close question as *"not a real question"* on account, that the given claim is widely known fact, and no one claims to the contrary. I've got response comment from OP:

> Where does it say in the FAQ that a contrary claim must exist for it
>   to be a real question?

So, should unquestioned claims be considered notable?

Comment: In general I don`t want to close questions just because we think we already know the answer. Though there probably needs to be some limit at least to avoid users asking questions about every basic scientific fact.

Comment: A claim which is considered a fact by many people (e.g. all mainstream scientists) might be considered wrong by other people. Look at all the creationists and conspiracy theorists for example. If of course "no one claims to the contrary" than it's might be different thing.