# Are questions about repeatable experiments on-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, off-topic

Are questions about the existence of repeatable, scientific experiments to validate a hypothesis on topic?

For example, there are two questions asking for experimental evidence for evolution, one of which is closed, one of which is not:

- [Are there any experiments that prove evolution?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/15082/18710)
- [Demonstrable and repeatable examples of evolution](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2057/18710)

Answer (score 2):

Tricky one. I'll start by addressing the examples you gave.

The first question you list (https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15082/are-there-any-experiments-that-prove-evolution) was a bit vague. It didn't ask for a notable claim (presumably some aspect of evolution) to be demonstrated to be true or false. It asked for help with lesson plans - experiments that student could conduct in optics and evolution. That is off-topic. It was rapidly voted closed.

I suspect it also suffered because we've seen creationists attempt to ask loaded questions about evolution, in bad faith. With a small amount of clicking, you will find the questioner is openly a Young-Earth Creationist, raising the question of whether his putative students (learning optics and evolution, from a teacher without resources?) actually exist.

The second question you list ([Demonstrable and repeatable examples of evolution](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/demonstrable-and-repeatable-examples-of-evolution)) was asked first. It was back in 2011 when the site was still new (in Beta? I haven't checked) and the community standards were still being developed. If it was asked again today, there would be pressure to turn it into a question about a skeptical claim, rather than an open-ended question looking for resources.

---

One interpretation of your original question is that it is asking whether a question like "Has [some notable scientific hypothesis] been supported with empirical evidence, such as repeatable experiments?" is on-topic.

With some caveats, the answer is yes. It is even okay if the [the scientific hypothesis is widely accepted](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1406/if-a-claim-is-commonly-accepted-does-questioning-it-require-a-notable-counter-c/), but note the caveats about good faith here too.

Answer (score 1):

> Are questions about the existence of repeatable, scientific experiments to validate a hypothesis on topic?

If you mean that the claim is that there are no repeatable scientific experiments on a topic then we ask:

- that the claim be believed by a significant amount of people
- that the topic is well-defined topic
- that the question be completely answerable in a few paragraphs
- that the question is well posed and answerable
- that answers are either wrong or right

If the above criteria are met, I think there's no problem.

In the example above, the old question clearly doesn't meet a few of these criteria, but we are keeping it for historical reasons. New questions should be more contained as above.